# Rails:5 Unable to display search by postcode/zipcode using the Geocoder Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

Building a small rails app that can search by postcode(zipcode) and radius, so it responds with contractors that are within that radius/postcode.

i can do Location.near("M20 2WZ", 15) in the rails console which gives me the relevant info.

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Location id: 12, company_name: "Redbridge Interiors Ltd", address: "16 Kennedy St", city: "manchester", postcode: "M2 4BY", latitude: 53.4799243, longitude: -2.2436708, created_at: "2017-07-11 11:39:03", updated_at: "2017-07-11 11:39:03">, #<Location id: 11, company_name: "Manchester Electrical Contractors Ltd", address: "Unit 9, The Schoolhouse, Second Ave", city: "Manchester", postcode: "M17 1DZ", latitude: 53.4646868, longitude: -2.3097547, created_at: "2017-07-11 11:36:57", updated_at: "2017-07-11 11:36:57">, #<Location id: 10, company_name: "J Hopkins (Contractors) Ltd", address: "Monde Trading Estate, Westinghouse Rd", city: "manchester", postcode: "M17 1LP", latitude: 53.4658142, longitude: -2.3278817, created_at: "2017-07-11 11:35:40", updated_at: "2017-07-11 11:35:40">]>
```

When i implement this in the app i get a url http://localhost:3000/locations?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=m20+2wz but get no info/data/locations

schema.rb

```
create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "company_name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end
```

location.rb

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?

  def full_address
   [address, city, postcode].compact.join(',')
  end
end
```

locations.controller.rb

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @locations = Location.all
    if params[:search].present?
      @locations = Location.near(params[:search], 10, :order => :distance)
    else
      @locations = Location.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  def new
    @location = Location.new
  end

  def show
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @location = Location.new(location_params)
    if @location.save
      flash[:success] = 'Place added!'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def location_params
    params.require(:location).permit(:company_name, :address, :city,
                                    :postcode, :latitude, :longitude)
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="starter-template">
    <h3>SubContractor Postcode search</h3>
      <p class="lead">Use this postcode search to quickly find subcontractors in your area</p>
      <p><%= form_tag locations_path, :method => :get do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "e.g M20 2WZ" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search Near", :name => nil %>
      </p>
    <% end %>

    </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :locations, except: [:update, :edit, :destroy]
  root 'locations#index'
end
```

Comment: Does this work? `@locations = Location.near(params[:search], 10)`

Comment: it goes to http://localhost:3000/locations?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=m20+2wz but does not give any other info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not displaying the locations in `index.html.erb`
Add this in your `index.html.erb`

```
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
<%= location.city %>
<% end %>
```